# Removing stop words from string using spacy in diffrent languages

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, stop-words

I have an array of strings in different languages and I would like to remove stop words from these strings.
example of string :

```
["mai fostul președinte egiptean mohamed morsi ", "em bon jovi lançou o álbum have a nice day a ", " otok škulj är en ö i kroatien den ligger i län"...]
```

this is the list of languages I'm willing to use :

```
['French',
 'Spanish',
 'Thai',
 'Russian',
 'Persian',
 'Indonesian',
 'Arabic',
 'Pushto',
 'Kannada',
 'Danish',
 'Japanese',
 'Malayalam',
 'Latin',
 'Romanian',
 'Swedish',
 'Portugese',
 'English',
 'Turkish',
 'Tamil',
 'Urdu',
 'Korean',
 'German',
 'Greek',
 'Italian',
 'Chinese',
 'Dutch',
 'Estonian',
 'Hindi']
```

I am using `Spacy` library, but I'm looking for something that support multiple languages.

what I have tried already:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("xx_ent_wiki_sm")
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

doc = nlp("This is a sentence about Facebook.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label) for ent in doc.ents])
all_stopwords = nlp.Defaults.stop_words
all_stopwords = nlp.Defaults.stop_words

data_text=df1['Text'] #here where i store my strings 

for x in data_text:
    text_tokens = word_tokenize(x)
    tokens_without_sw=[word for word in text_tokens if not word inall_stopwords]

print(tokens_without_sw)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('french')`, or `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('spanish')`, etc? Seems like you already have a library capable of getting stopwords. Unfortunately, it wouldn't cover the more obscure languages on your list. For example, it doesn't have Thai stopwords, or Tamil stopwords.

Comment: @NickODell that's the problem... the nltk doesn't support all my languages.

Comment: you'd better download each language from its unofficial source. For instance, Perian can be found [here](https://github.com/sobhe/hazm/blob/master/hazm/data/stopwords.dat)

Comment: If you know which sentences are in which language, a cheap way to remove stop words is to count the frequency of every word by language,  then sort the words by frequency: the top N frequent words correspond (more or less) to stop words. You need to do this separately for every language, otherwise you'll just obtain the most frequent languages in your data,